# how to configure muiti datasource in springboot + mybatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

Here is the problem, I need to configure additional datasource in my project.

There was only one datasource before, so I just configured one single datasource in `application.properties`, and then i coded like this:

```
@Repository
public class DrClusterManagerImpl implements DrClusterManager {


private final SqlSession sqlSession;

public DrClusterManagerImpl(SqlSession sqlSession) {
    this.sqlSession = sqlSession;
}
}
```

it works fine, thanks to springboot, but now I'm puzzled that how can i inject a specific `sqlsession` into this bean?

I've checked springboot reference, but it's not helpful.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Comment: One of the approaches  I see that you can put repositories to the different packages and then add appropriate @EntityScan(basePackageClasses=RepositoryPackagesDatasourceA.class) and @EntityScan(basePackageClasses=RepositoryPackagesDatasourceB.class) to your data sources configurations. So, then you will now what SqlSession will be injected to the specific repository.

Comment: thx, i'll give it a shot.

Comment: See link of an article using datasource for different databases. You can use the same concept for different data sources. https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7